# Imagemagick not working with png files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, macos, imagemagick

For some reason my imagemagick cant process any png files. They all complain with something like the following (can be replicated easily using identify -format %wx%h afile.png ):

```
identify: memory allocation failed `afile.png' @ error/png.c/ReadOnePNGImage/2123.
identify: corrupt image `afile.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3668.
```

Jpegs work fine. But no matter what png file I create on photoshop or download of the net it wont work.

I am using mac os x 10.5 and imagemagick 6.7.1-0 2011-08-01 Q8

```
CONFIGURE     ./configure  '--prefix=/usr/local' '--disable-static' '--with-modules' '--without-perl' '--without-magick-plus-plus' '--with-quantum-depth=8' '--disable-openmp' '--with-gs-font-dir=/usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts' 'LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib' 'CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include'
CONFIGURE_PATH /usr/local/etc/ImageMagick/
COPYRIGHT     Copyright (C) 1999-2011 ImageMagick Studio LLC
CPPFLAGS      -I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick
CXX           g++
CXXFLAGS      -g -O2 -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread
DEFS          -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
DELEGATES     bzlib freetype jpeg jng lcms2 png tiff x11 xml zlib
DISTCHECK_CONFIG_FLAGS 'CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include' 'LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib' --disable-deprecated --with-umem=no --with-autotrace=no --with-gslib=no --with-fontpath= --with-gs-font-dir=/usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts --with-perl=no
DOCUMENTATION_PATH /usr/local/share/doc/ImageMagick-6.7.1/
EXEC-PREFIX   /usr/local
EXECUTABLE_PATH /usr/local/bin
FEATURES      
FILTER_PATH   /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-6.7.1/modules-Q8/filters
HOST          i386-apple-darwin9.8.0
LDFLAGS       -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/X11/lib -R/usr/X11/lib
LIB_VERSION   0x671
LIB_VERSION_NUMBER 6,7,1,0
LIBRARY_PATH  /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-6.7.1
LIBS          -lMagickCore -llcms2 -ltiff -lfreetype -ljpeg -lXext -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lXt -lbz2 -lz -lm -lpthread 
NAME          ImageMagick
```

I have googled everything but cant seem to get a handle on it. I am able to change settings in Imagemagick but I cant really pass in params to the function calls as I am calling this lib through a ruby on rails third party gem. Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you have installed the requisite PNG libraries and build ImageMagick with those libraries included.

The best instructions for building ImageMagick for use with rmagick (the Ruby on Rails gem) are at the source - http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-linux.html

Some additional notes, run your ./configure command again, or check your configure log, and look for the summary section (it is noted in the document linked above or just search for "ImageMagick is configured as follows". There you will see a list of libraries it is attempting to use and what are found. You should see a line like:

```
PNG               --with-png=yes                yes
```

If it says --with-png=no, or if it has the value "no", then that is your problem. You need to install the png libs. And make sure you install the png-devel libs too, since they are needed for building from source. Now, when you run ./configure, it should discover the png libs and included them in the build.

One last final note, not covered in the document linked above, is that you might need to include --disable-openmp in your ./configure parameters, depending on your hardware. And it looks like you have included it, so you should be good.