# Rails 3 - better to create more thumbnails or only one and resize it by CSS?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, image, paperclip, thumbnails

I am building little shop application and now thinking about the faster way, how to upload images - I need images in 4 sizes. The first idea - from upload create 4 thumbnails and that's all - probably the easiest way, but what I am worried - creating 4 sizes through upload can take lot of time... that's what I don't like and I would like to avoid it.

The second idea is upload image - for example in the size 300x300 and in a moment, when I would need in the shop display thumb of this image, so in HTML and CSS I just set the value **:style => 'width: 165px;'**.

What you think about that? What would be the best variant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this question relates to rails, but is a more general one.

Typically, you do want to create the images in all sizes they would be utilized. Creating four sizes at the time of upload doesn't usually take that much time (I am referring to uploading the image once and then creating the needed images on the server side based on that) - at least if you compare it to combined time of users all downloading the biggest size image and then resizing it on the fly when all they need is a small thumbnail. Normally, uploading the images does not happen that often. Generating the other images could also possibly be deferred to a scheduled job that would run nightly, so it wouldn't impact the user experience on the admin side.

That said, if your users have to anyways every time download the biggest image, it would be in the cache anyway and no extra overhead would incur if you then resize it using css wherever you need it in a smaller size. In that case I would think it would be ok just to use the biggest size. Usually you can avoid using the biggest size images on most use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [carrierwave gem](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) to manage your uploads. Configure the gem with multiple "versions".

As eis suggests, processing the images is not the performance bottleneck, but if you really want to get fancy use the [delayed_job gem](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) to handle the processing asynchronously.

When configuring carrierwave, you will also need to setup the actual processor. I use the full-blown rmagick, but you can use minimagick which is simpler to setup. It's all detailed in the carrierwave readme. For rmagick/imagemagick, [here's a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109536/imagemagick-not-working-with-png-files/8122453#8122453) that touches on that.

Also, as eis suggests, images are generally cached reliably by the browser, and these days browsers do a decent job of resizing images on the fly, though generally, the better the processor, the better the results, and that's why I use rmagick.

One last note, unless you can dictate what users are selecting for upload, you will most likely need to process the image at least one. E.g., someone might upload a huge 8000 X 6000 pixel image with little compression. You would not want to serve up that image since you have less control. And once you've gone to the trouble of setting up the image processing, it's a trivial thing to add a few more output sizes to fit the various display contexts.